# deletar dois registro do banco

Tags: php, mysql

to tentando excluir dois registro do banco em tabela diferentes, ao clicar o botao de excluir iria deletar os registros da tabela.

a conexao de cada tabela.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$idcontratoItEvento = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idcontratoItEvento', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!empty($idcontratoItEvento)){
    $result_usuario = "DELETE FROM contratoItEvento WHERE idcontratoItEvento='$idcontratoItEvento'";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result_usuario);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli)){
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<script>alert('Eventos dos Itens Contrato apagado com sucesso!');</script>"";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        
        // $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Erro o usuário não foi apagado com sucesso</p>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}else{  
    // $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Necessário selecionar um usuário</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}




<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$idContratoItem  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idContratoItem', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!empty($idContratoItem)){
    $result_usuario = "DELETE FROM ContratoItem WHERE idContratoItem='$idContratoItem'";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result_usuario);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli)){
        $_SESSION['msg1'] = "<script>alert('Itens de Contrato apagado com sucesso!');</script>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        
        $_SESSION['msg1'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Erro o usuário não foi apagado com sucesso</p>";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}else{  
    $_SESSION['msg1'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Necessário selecionar um usuário</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
} 





 <tbody id='tboby'>
        <?php 
             $dado =  [];
                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM   ContratoItem";
                $conexao = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die ($mysqli->error);
                 while ($dado = $conexao->fetch_array()) {
                    ?>
                <tr onclick="showHideRow(<?php echo $dado["idContratoItem"]; ?>)">        
                        <td><?php echo $dado["idContratoItem"];?></td>                        
                        <td><?php echo $dado["codProd"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["idproduto"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["descProd"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["codunidmed"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["valorFixo"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["percent"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["valor"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dado["primeiroPreco"]; ?></td>   
                        <td><?php echo $dado["primeiroPercent"]; ?></td>    
                        <td> 
                            
                        <?php          
                        //retornando a id que selecionou da td na url para o link                                                                                          
                        echo '<a href="adicionar.php?idContratoItem='.$dado['idContratoItem'].'"><button button style="background-color: #3c3c3c; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: #fff; width: 120px; border: none; font-size: 13px; margin: 3px;
                        padding: 4px 8px;
                        left: 0px;">Adiconar Evento</button></a></a>';   

                        echo '<a href="delete.php?idContratoItem='.$dado['idContratoItem'].'" class="delete"><button button style="background-color: #3c3c3c; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: #fff; width: 120px; border: none; font-size: 13px; margin: 3px;
                        padding: 4px 8px;
                        left: 0px;">Deletar</button></a></a>'; 
                                              
                        ?>                            
                        </td>                                                           
                </tr>                    
        <?php } ?>   

        
    </tbody>
```

seria o botão pra fazer a exclusão do registro no banco

```
  echo '<a href="delete.php?idContratoItem='.$dado['idContratoItem'].'" class="delete"><button button style="background-color: #3c3c3c; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: #fff; width: 120px; border: none; font-size: 13px; margin: 3px;
                            padding: 4px 8px;
                            left: 0px;">Deletar</button></a></a>';
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Qual o problema ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Talvez esteja querendo saber sobre MySQL, exemplo:

MySQL para deletar um único registro id:

```
DELETE FROM `tabela` WHERE id = 1
```

MySQL para deletar um 2 ou até vários registro id para a mesma tabela:

```
DELETE FROM `tabela` WHERE id in(1,2,3)
```

Onde dentro dos parente, id in(1,2,3), significa o mesmo que selecionar id= 1, id=2, id=3, etc....
Vai conter os números dos respectivos ids que você deseja apagar, lembrando que isso é uma ação que deve ser usada com cuidado pois apaga muitos registros em uma única ação.

Agora caso você queira deletar vários registros de tabelas diferente?
Ai tem que usar dois comando MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM `tabela1` WHERE id = 1
DELETE FROM `tabela2` WHERE id = 1
```